# Compare 3 dates

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to add some VBA code to compare dates in 3 columns and output the greatest (most recent) date into my worksheet.

I currently have code to compare 2 date columns that I have defined as variables and return the value to the worksheet, however I need a little help in knowing how I can compare 3 date columns, the third date column would be:

PPD_3_Date = Worksheets("Data").Range("AS" & i)

Here is the function I currently am using:

```
Function PPDdate()

Dim PPD_1_Date As Date
Dim PPD_2_Date As Date
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

j = Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
k = Worksheets("Error").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
For i = 2 To lstrow

PPD_1_Date = Worksheets("Data").Range("AW" & i)
PPD_2_Date = Worksheets("Data").Range("BA" & i)
Entity = Worksheets("Data").Range("J" & i)
Dept = Worksheets("Data").Range("M" & i)
TSpot_Date = Worksheets("Data").Range("AS" & i)

If PPD_1_Date > PPD_2_Date Then
   Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("A" & j & ":C" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Value
   Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("F" & j).Value = PPD_1_Date
   Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("G" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("AX" & i).Value
   Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("H" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("AZ" & i).Value
   Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("I" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("AY" & i).Value
   j = j + 1
Else
  If PPD_1_Date < PPD_2_Date Then
    Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("A" & j & ":C" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Value
    Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("F" & j).Value = PPD_2_Date
    'Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("G" & j).Value = "ELSE IF CONDITION"
    Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("G" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("BB" & i).Value
    Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("H" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("BD" & i).Value
    Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("I" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("BC" & i).Value
    j = j + 1
  Else
    'If IsEmpty(Worksheets("Data").Range(PPD_1_Date & i).Value) = True And IsEmpty(Worksheets("Data").Range(PPD_2_Date & i).Value) = True Then
      'GoTo EmptyRange
    'Else
    If (InStr(1, Entity, "CNG Hospital") Or InStr(1, Entity, "Home Health") Or InStr(1, Entity, "Hospice") Or InStr(1, Dept, "Volunteers")) And IsEmpty(TSpot_Date) = True Then
    Worksheets("Error").Range("A" & k & ":H" & k).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Value
    Worksheets("Error").Range("F" & k).Value = "REVIEW PPD DATA"
    k = k + 1
    Else
    Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("A" & j & ":C" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & i & ":C" & i).Value
    Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("F" & j).Value = TSpot_Date
    Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("G" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("AX" & i).Value
    Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("H" & j).Value = Worksheets("Data").Range("AY" & i).Value
    Worksheets("PPDCI").Range("I" & j).Value = "NO PPD DATES BUT HAS TSPOT DATE"
    j = j + 1

    End If

  End If

End If

Next i

End Function
```

This is running on Office 365 client. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your question? It doesn't seem to me that you could really trim this code

Comment: If your question is only 'how would i add a third date to the comparison' you would just use `ElseIf Date_1 > Date_3 Then` instead of `Else` to include whichever new cases you need to handle

Comment: Maybe there's something I don't understand but your description makes it sound like you can do this task without using VBA at all.

Comment: I was trying to encapsulate all the logic changes into VBA. I didn't if putting the dates into an array and then extracting the greatest date from the array would work.

Answer (score 4):

There is already a function for finding the largest date in a range, `Application.WorksheetFunction.Max`:

[image]

Just input the range which contains the dates, or the dates themself, and it will spit out the largest one.

To *"to compare dates in 3 columns and output the greatest (most recent) date into my worksheet"*, you'd do the following, assuming your dates are stored in `PPData1-3`

```
Sub PPDDate()
  Dim PPD_1_Date As Date
  Dim PPD_2_Date As Date
  Dim PPD_3_Date As Date

  PPD_1_Date = Sheet1.Range("A2")
  PPD_2_Date = Sheet1.Range("B2")
  PPD_3_Date = Sheet1.Range("C2")

  Sheet1.Range("A1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(PPD_1_Date, PPD_2_Date, PPD_3_Date)
  Sheet1.Range("A1").NumberFormat = "dd.mm.yyyy"
End Sub
```

Or simply put the formula directly into the cell which you want the largest one to be printed in as shown in the screenshot.

If you instead want to do various stuff based on which date is the largest, I might do something like the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PPDDate()
    Dim PPD_1_Date As Date
    Dim PPD_2_Date As Date
    Dim PPD_3_Date As Date
    Dim largest_date As Date

    PPD_1_Date = Sheet1.Range("A2")
    PPD_2_Date = Sheet1.Range("B2")
    PPD_3_Date = Sheet1.Range("C2")

    Select Case Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(PPD_1_Date, PPD_2_Date, PPD_3_Date)
        Case PPD_1_Date:
            ' Do stuff for case 1
            Debug.Print "1"
        Case PPD_2_Date:
            ' Do stuff for case 2
            Debug.Print "2"
        Case PPD_3_Date:
            ' Do stuff for case 3
            Debug.Print "3"
        Case Else:
            MsgBox Prompt:="Something went wrong", Title:="Something went wrong", Buttons:=vbExclamation
    End Select
End Sub
```

If two of the dates are equal, I believe it is the first case which will be executed - if this matters you may need to change things around a bit.

Comment: Whats the best way of using that function in VBA? Thanks

Comment: @nick I've updated the answer with a couple of code samples - hopefully this can get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you! This will be helpful!

Comment: @nick Glad to be of help! If you find that my answer solves your problem, I'd really appreciate it if you marked it as your accepted answer.